Adding drivers and updates to Windows ISO
How can I prepare an updated and loaded ISO? I want it with a driver so that it can be installed automatically when I plug in a USB.

How you slipstream drivers onto a Windows ISO is well documented.  Do you have a specific step of that process you are stuck on? Any event you can use DISM to modify the contents of an Windows ISO. However, unless it's a USB 3 driver for Windows 7, it's probably not actually necessary.
